# Reducing bias when forecasting retail sales with boosting model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, boosting, bias

I'm forecasting future sales for products in retail stores, using a LightGBM model. My model has a decent forecast accuracy, but the forecasts are biased (the average forecast error is negative, the model is consistently under-forecasting). Do you have any idea or tips on how to avoid bias when forecasting time series with boosting models?

Here are some more details:

- I'm making forecasts at the Day x Product x Store granularity (i.e 1 forecast every day for each product in each store).
- The forecasting horizon is +7 days.
- I'm training a single model to forecast all products, stores and time horizons.
- The main features are lags of sales, calendar info (day of the week, month...), product info (category, price) and store info.
- Evaluation is made with a time-based cross-validation.

Comment: Are your series generally trending upwards?  That would do it, as the future is not the same as the past and tree-based models have a hard time extrapolating beyond the bounds of the data.

Comment: Yes exactly. Do you have any idea on how to help tree-based models better extrapolating the trend?

Comment: I'll write up a fuller answer (this is exactly the business I'm in, or was until I transitioned into inventory control a few months ago), but the short version is a recommendation along the lines of implementing a two-stage forecast.  The first stage might be Holt-Winters with a 7-day seasonal period; that should pick up trend + most of the week seasonality, and would run at the product x store level.  The second stage is to build the boosting or RF model using the features on the residuals from the H-W models, as you do now with the raw sales.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea, but there are maybe too many different products (> 1000 products): training thousands of H-W models might be too computationally expensive. Also, could you please explain how you leverage the output of H-W models in the boosting model? I'm not sure to understand why you use the residuals instead of the H-W prediction.

Comment: H-W or similar algorithms are really quite fast, especially if you are using multithreading - which is easy to do in R or Python.   You could use the prediction, true, but then the GBM or whatever has to use some of your valuable data points "learning" that the prediction helps predict - why put it to this effort when you already know that?

Comment: Hi @jbowman would be great if you could write up an answer :)

Comment: @ML-ATF - how did you solve this issue in the end?

Comment: @shiftyscales - all right, better late than never!  I'll construct a working example as well.

Comment: @jbowman - quick question while you are working on this answer; would you use in-sample or out-of-sample residuals to train the ML model? I am inclined towards OOS.